# Android set up proxy for cellular signal

Tags: android

I am using Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet. I can add proxy for WiFi. Can I do the same for celluar comnnection ? If yes, how ?

OR can I package browser so that there can be limit on web sites visited ?

Thanks,

Comment: Reopen: this question is directly related with developers proxy configurations for debugging android apps and browsing etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proxies may not work on all cellular operators. And make sure to provide proper access point name

Settings > More > Mobile Networks > Access point Names > (tap to edit your APN or create a new APN)> Proxy & Port

Here are screenshots taken from my galaxy tab 10.1 running Android 4.2.1(CyanogenMod10.1)

Step1
  [image: Step 1]

Step 2[image: Select Mobile networks]

Step 3 : Tap to edit or create a new APN
[image]

Step 4 Enter your proxy IP and port(one in the screen shot is not valid)
[image]

Comment: Thanks! My tablet is running Android 4.0.4. These options are not available on it. I guess I will have to wait for update.